# Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent using Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am attempting to render a view using JS, Node, and Express but am getting this error 'Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent'. I know it's something to do with asynchronous callbacks, but 
I can't work out exactly how to fix it.

The problem doesn't seem to be with the res.redirect (removing it doesn't display the data) but rather with the `res.render` and `var spaces` not loading in properly to the EJS, we think.  When we put `spaces`, we get the message "object Promise".

```
const userController = require('../controllers').user;
const spaceController = require('../controllers').space;

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.render('index.ejs');
  });

  app.post('/users/new', function(req,res){
    userController.create(req,res);
    res.redirect('/');
  });

  app.get('/spaces', function(req, res) {
    var spaces = spaceController.retrieve(req,res);
    res.render('spaces/index.ejs', {spaces});

  });

  app.get('/spaces/new', function(req, res) {
    res.render('spaces/new.ejs');
  });

  app.post('/spaces/new', function(req,res){
    spaceController.create(req,res);
    res.redirect('/spaces');
  });

};
```

And my controller:

```
const Space = require('../models').Space;

module.exports = {
  create(req, res) {
    return Space
    .create({
      name: req.body.name,
      description: req.body.description,
      price: req.body.price,
    })
    .then(space => res.status(201).send(space))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  },

  retrieve(req, res) {
    return Space
    .findAll()
    .then(space => {
      if (!space) {
        return res.status(404).send({
          message: 'Space Not Found',
        });
      }
      return res.status(200).send(space);
    })
    .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  },
};
```

And my view:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>MakersBnB</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- load bootstrap css -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- load fontawesome -->
     <style>
         body        { padding-top:80px; }
     </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">

 <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
   <div class="jumbotron text-center">

     <h1>Book a Space</h1>

<form action="/spaces/new" method="get">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">List a space</button>

</form>

<div class="spaces">
  <% spaces.each(function(space) { %>
        <ul>
          <li><%= space.name %></a></li>
          <li><%= space.description %></li>
          <li>£ <%= space.price %></li>
        </ul>
        <% });%>
</div>


 </div>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: The problem is that your Controller responds to the request and so does the router. For example app.get('/spaces'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are sending multiple responses for some of your requests. You can only send one response for a request.

For example in your `/users/new` route, you first make a call to `userController.create`. `userController.create` sends a response as part of the body of the function.

Your code then goes back to the callback for your `/users/new` route and calls the `res.redirect('/')` which invokes your `/` route which also returns a response.

To fix, let your controller handle sending the response.

For example:

```
app.post('/users/new', userController.create);
```

In the body of the controller functions, you can also choose which view to render

```
app.get('/spaces', spaceController.retrieve);
```

and in the controller:

```
 retrieve(req, res) {
    return Space
    .findAll()
    .then(spaces => {
      if (!spaces) {
        return res.status(404).send({
          message: 'Space Not Found',
        });
      }
      return res.status(200).render('spaces/index.ejs', {spaces});
    })
    .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

these routes

```
 app.post('/users/new', function(req,res){
    userController.create(req,res);
    res.redirect('/');
  });

  app.get('/spaces', function(req, res) {
    var spaces = spaceController.retrieve(req,res);
    res.render('spaces/index.ejs', {spaces});

  })
 app.post('/spaces/new', function(req,res){
    spaceController.create(req,res);
    res.redirect('/spaces');
  });
```

the logic inside `spaceController` already handle the response to the client asynchronously (both for success and fail)

but you send a synchronous response immediatly (`res.redirect`) that will prevent you to send the async response later. this triggers the exception.

removing the `res.redirect` instruction from the three routes should fix it.

Comment: Didn't fix it, unfortunately - the issue is with the `res.render` and `var spaces` not loading in properly to the EJS, we think.  When we put `spaces`, we get the message "object Promise".

Comment: The exception is pretty self explanatory, you're trying to send a response to the client when you already sent one. Maybe you have some other errors in your code, but to fix the exception focus on when you send back the response

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/users/new', function(req,res){
    userController.create(req,res);
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

You are basically starting Space.create() as async and before it finishes you are responding with a redirect.

you could try

```
app.post('/users/new', 
        userController.create,
        (res,req) => res.redirect('/')
      );
```

The redirect will never be reached with that but you could have userController.create return next() like this

```
create(req, res, next) {
    return Space
    .create({
      name: req.body.name,
      description: req.body.description,
      price: req.body.price,
    })
    .then((space) => {      
      res.locals.space = space || {};
      return next();
    })
    .catch(error => next(error));
  }
```

with this middleware

```
app.post('/users/new', 
        userController.create,
        (res,req) => res.status(200).send(res.locals.space)
      );
```

Examples from recent project:
https://github.com/JellyKid/ballsavr/tree/master/Backend/lib